# wine as a cross compiler with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, linux, wine

I am using Linux, and my client uses Windows. When I use pyinstaller to make exe file from python script my client cannot run it on its windows os.

I looked for cross compiler. Installed wine on my linux. But, now I am totally lost on what to do next.
Do I need install python through wine? how to go next step any ideas?